# Remove Windows Warning when Deleting Root Certificate

Tags: c#, certificate, x509certificate

We are wanting to delete some of our own certificates when doing a new install of our application. The code works, but the user is made aware that something is being deleted. Is there any way to remove the certificate without that windows box showing? Below is the code I am using and the message that I am referring to. I appreciate any help!!

```
            try
            {
                X509Store rootStore = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
                rootStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite | OpenFlags.IncludeArchived);
                X509Certificate2Collection rootCol = rootStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "United Systems CA", false);

                foreach (var cert in rootCol)
                {
                    rootStore.Remove(cert);
                }
                rootStore.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                uis.ShowMessageBox("Existing Current User Root Certificates could not be deleted. Please contact support. ");
            }
```

[image: Warning Message]

Answer (score 0):

You can't. This dialog is hardcoded in the `CertDeleteCertificateFromStore` and in `CertDeleteCertificateFromStore` functions when you manage Trusted Root CAs store in the current user context. And this message is not avoidable.

Comment: That is so unfortunate.

Comment: this dialog was made unavoidable for security reasons -- to protect internet-enabled applications (say, web browsers) from rogue root certificate installation in the current user store when user visits suspicious web site.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code (slightly modified) with admin permissions on Windows 7. No window has been shown. Maybe this is the key. I did not try it without admin permissions.

Here is the code:

```
try
{
    X509Store rootStore = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    rootStore.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
    X509Certificate2Collection rootCol = rootStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "b5 61 eb ea a4 de e4 25 4b 69 1a 98 a5 57 47 c2 34 c7 d9 71", false);

    foreach (var cert in rootCol)
    {
        rootStore.Remove(cert);
    }
    rootStore.Close();
}
catch
{
    Console.Write("Existing Current User Root Certificates could not be deleted. Please contact support. ");
}
```

Comment: I was super hopeful, but sadly I still get this message. I am running as admin, but I am finding by the issuer name instead of the thumbprint so I suppose that may make a difference.

Comment: What about `OpenFlags` in store.Open method? I used `OpenFlags.MaxAllowed`.

Comment: Still did not work. It must be with how the certificate itself was setup. :(